# How to use .sdf files in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, sql-server-ce

In .NET framework, we can load the **.sdf file** using System.Data.Linq.DataContext. But this is not available in **.NET Core**

```
public partial class Northwind : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
   private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();
   ....
   public Northwind(string connection) :
      base(connection, mappingSource)
   {
      OnCreated();
   }

 .....
 public System.Data.Linq.Table<Categories> Categories 
 {
    get
    {
       return this.GetTable<Categories>();
    }
 }

 public System.Data.Linq.Table<Customers> Customers
 {
    get
    {
       return this.GetTable<Customers>();
    }
 }

 public System.Data.Linq.Table<Employees> Employees
 {
    get
    {
       return this.GetTable<Employees>();
    }
 }

 public System.Data.Linq.Table<OrderDetails> OrderDetails
 {
    get
    {
       return this.GetTable<OrderDetails>();
    }
 }

 public System.Data.Linq.Table<Orders> Orders
 {
    get
    {
       return this.GetTable<Orders>();
    }
 }

 public System.Data.Linq.Table<Products> Products
 {
    get
    {
       return this.GetTable<Products>();
    }
 }
}


// Getting Data
private void PopulateData()
{
  Random r = new Random();

  Northwind north = new Northwind(string.Format(@"Data Source= {0}", 
  FindFile("Northwind.sdf")));

  foreach (OrderDetails orderDet in north.OrderDetails.Take(50))
  {
      OrderInfo orderInfo = new OrderInfo();
      orderInfo.OrderID = orderDet.OrderID;
      orderInfo.CustomerID = orderDet.Orders.CustomerID;
      orderInfo.ProductName = orderDet.Products.ProductName;
      orderInfo.UnitPrice = (double)orderDet.UnitPrice;
      orderInfo.OrderDate = (DateTime)orderDet.Orders.OrderDate;
      orderInfo.DeliveryDelay = (DateTime)orderDet.Orders.ShippedDate - 
orderInfo.OrderDate;
      orderInfo.Quantity = orderDet.Quantity;

      orderInfo.ContactNumber = r.Next(999111234, 999111239).ToString();

      orderInfo.ShipAddress = orderDet.Orders.ShipAddress;

      _orderList.Add(orderInfo);
  }
}
```

Data for the application will be retrieved using DataContext in .NET Framework application, now in .NET Core, we could not work with loading .sdf files.

How can we use **.sdf files in .NET Core?**

Comment: do you have example code on .net framework side? can you share?

Comment: SQL Server Compact Edition (CE) which uses the `.sdf` database files has long been discontinued. I highly doubt that MS will be supporting it in .NET Core ever....

Comment: `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` is part of LINQ To SQL, itself on life support ever since Entity Framework came out. By now, it's rarely used. It was only meant as an "example" provider in any case, not a full-featured ORM. There's little chance it will be ported to .NET Core, at least not by Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ADO.NET provider directly, but only on Windows.

Some sample code and tips here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33897#issuecomment-536269132